# Duplicate URLs in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, url, duplicates

I am developing a ZF website: howtowritecitations (dot) com
and it has a TOS page:
howtowritecitations (dot) com/termsofservice

But what are these duplicate pages?

```
http://www.howtowritecitations.com/termsofservice/index
http://www.howtowritecitations.com/index.php/termsofservice
http://www.howtowritecitations.com/index.php/index/termsofservice
```

Where did they come from? Will this be a problem? I hope not. For example, when Google crawls the page, it will only find and index howtowritecitations (dot) com/termsofservice, right?

If it is a potential problem, show me in the right direction so I can try and solve it.

Someone suggested to start looking at getRequestUri() in routeShutdown() (or something similar) 
to use preg_replace to remove index.php, in order to 301-redirect to the proper URL, but I lost here.

Thanks in advance for advice or comments

Comment: The first two are normal and expected with default routes, the third one is different. It looks like you have a `termsofservice` action in your index controller. Removing `index.php` from your url's is pretty simple check out [Rob Allen's Blog](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/remove-index-php-from-your-url/)

Comment: What do you mean with duplicate pages? How does your .htaccess look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the routes you have setup. By default, Zend Framework applications usually route like:

```
www.yoursite.com/:controller/:action/:param
```

Right now, your termsofservice controller located at `www.yoursite.com/termsofservice` when called will show the :index action by default when no action is specified without changing the URL. It is also perfectly valid to access it using `www.yoursite.com/termsofservice/index`.

In order to fix these, you need to setup custom routes where everything that matches `www.yoursite.com/:controller/*` will route to `www.yoursite.com/:controller`. That way Google will never get a chance to see an alternate URL to index.

Comment: OK, many thanks. Besides that potential google-related problem I disussed, are there anything else? I mean, the SEO thing aside, is this this a real problem, or is it more or less safe to ignore it? Tricky to anwser, I would imagine, given that it is pretty much up tp me, but I just need to me pointed in the right direction in terms of general advice. Kent

Comment: Its relatively safe just a little awkward in search results and the potential for bad SEO due to what appears as duplicate content. I would at minimum route the one containing "index.php" to the preferred link just so malicious web trolls don't have an easy "hey I'm using PHP" flag.

Comment: Cillosis, @RockyFord, and others:
Hello again, thanks for your input. All alternate links are now corrected. They will direct you to the same target, for example:
http://www.howtowritecitations.com/termsofservice
And this behavior is the same for all pages (except my forum, not part the zend framwork).
The problem is reduced (gone?) now, I hope. Any comments are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kent I'm glad that helped. If you liked my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you.